# Yii2 conditional validation rule on basis of minimum value

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I have 2 fields in a form pricemark and price, when user select pricemark value = `other` user can not enter a value less than 250. I need a validation rule for it in `yii2` but its not working . here is my code

```
        ['price', 'min' => 250, 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->priceMark == 'other';
        }],
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? Or maybe it is working on server side but on the client side and you want both?

Comment: currently its not working, I am primarily looking for server side but if able to get it work on client side as well that would be great

Comment: So just to make it clear - does it work on the server side?

Comment: no its not working , does code looks ok to you ?

Comment: Oh, right - there is error, let me prepare proper answer.

Comment: OK I got it too, silly me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
['price', 'number', 'min' => 250, 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->priceMark == 'other';
}, 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
    return $("<field>").val() == "other";
}'],
```

where `<field>` is the `priceMark` element identifier like its class or ID (i.e. `#price_pricemark` if model name is `Price`).

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I did not specify the type of attribute for validation. the correct code should be

```
        ['price', 'integer', 'min' => 250, 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->priceMark == 'other';
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return $('#uploadform-pricemark').val() == 'other';
        }"],
```

see `integer` after price attribute I missed it , also I added client side code which is also working fine now.

,